# how to complete (update) a mongoDB document

Tags: javascript, mongodb, api, npm

I am facing the following situation:

I have a api request from one service who create multiple mongo documents in one collection for example:

```
[
{_id: 1, test1: 2, test: 3},
{_id: 2, test1: 3, test: 4}
]
```

after this a second service read these documents and search another part of the information, so I am building an object like:

```
[
{_id: 1,  newValue: 4},
{_id: 2,  newValue: 4}
]
```

my question is: can I using the "_id" value update all the documents at once ? the problem is that I don't want to update one per one the documents because there are to many, so I am guessing that is better delete all these documents and insert them with all information, what do you think ?

Comment: the purpose is have the information like this:

[
{_id: 1, test1: 2, test: 3, newValue: 4},
{_id: 2, test1: 3, test: 4, newValue: 4}
]

Comment: Do you seek something like this:   "set newValue = 4 where _id in [1,2,3,4,...]"?

Comment: that wasn't best example because the "newValue" column will have different values for each document

Comment: OK, so there's no getting around the fact that if each `_id` gets a different `newValue`, somewhere your code logic has to accommodate this, even if you deleted everything and "reinserted" them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A mass deletion followed by "re-insertion" is a bit heavy handed and will also take its toll on index management.   Doing multiple updates in bulk using `bulkWrite` is the better way:

```
var bulkOps = [];

for each thing you need to process {
        set up _id and newValue ... ;
        bulkOps.push({
          "updateOne": {
                    "filter": { "_id": theOneYouAreWorkingOn },
                    update: { $set: {"newValue": theTargetValue } }
                }
            });
    });

// Send a single big bundle of updates.  This could also be wrapped in a transaction:
printjson( db.foo.bulkWrite(bulkOps) );
```